# How to update a field in a firestore document after an x amount of time?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

We have a document that has a time field parameter, we need firebase to check whether a certain amount of time has elapsed since document creation. If that amount of time has elapsed we need to update a field in that same document. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try searching timers and future delays in flutter. its really simple.

Comment: how would future delays help, I need firebase to update automatically on time elapsed.

Comment: you could set the delay duration in future delays. You could also do the same thing using timers. Run the timer or delay once you've successfully created the document.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cloud function which triggers when a document is created.
 In this function you can use timers like setTimeout() to execute a function which changes the document

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('my-collection/{doc-id}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => { setTimeout(updateDocFunction,time) });
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work, what would updateDocFunction be, if you could give me an example?

Comment: It should be the function that you create where you can handle what should be updated in the document. If this method does not work check the logs and comment the problem.

Comment: I'm facing a few errors,
1. const functions = require('firebase-functions'); error: const variables must have a constant value
2. Undefined name 'exports'.
3. The method 'setTimeout' isn't defined for the type '_PollConfirmationPageState'.

Comment: This code must be created in cloud functions. This is written in node js. This code is not added in your app code, this is added in on the cloud, view firebase docs for cloud functions.